# Central limit theorem, need help discovering how to calculate some variables

Tags: probability, statistics

This is the problem:

The service time at an information desk in minutes, is a random variable $X$ with the following probability density function:
$$f_X(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{2x}{21}, & 10 \leq x \leq 11 \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$$

$(X_1, X_2, ..., X_{100})$ is a vector of independent random variables with the same distribution as $X$. Calculate the probability of the arithmetic average of these $100$ variables exceed $105148$ minutes.

My attempt:
$$ Z = \frac{\bar X - n\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}} \sim \operatorname{Normal}(0,1) $$

$$\Pr[\bar X > 105148] = 1 - \Pr[\bar X \le 105148] = 1 - \Pr\left[\frac{105148 - 100\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{100}}\right] =  \large{?}$$

Can you help me please?

Comment: You need to compute the appropriate integrals to get $\mu $ and $\sigma $. (Also if your numerator contains the sample mean rather than the sum then the thing you subtract is just $\mu $ not $n \mu $.)

Comment: can you tell me just which integrals, I can compute them, I just don't know which are the appropriate integrals in this case.
let me check if i get it, in the numerator it will be $0,105148 - μ$ and not $10,5148 - nμ$?

Comment: Your textbook will give you the formulae for the expected value and standard deviation of $X$; these involve integrals. And yes, if you refer to the formulation of the CLT, the approximate standard normal is ${\bar X-\mu \over \sqrt{n}\, \sigma}$.

Comment: @A.G. Nope, you messed it up too. It's either $\frac{\sum_i X_i - n \mu}{\sigma \sqrt{n}}$ or $\frac{\overline{X}-\mu}{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}}$.

Comment: i think i got it, can you confirm my answer to the problem which is $0.406627$

Comment: @Ian. Correct --- my typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mean and variance of $X$ are
$$
\mu=\int_{10}^{11} {2\, x\over 21}\, dx= {662\over 63}\approx 10.5079
$$
and
$$
\sigma^2=\int_{10}^{11} \left({2\, x\over 21}\right)^2\, dx - \mu^2 = {661\over7938} \approx 0.0832703.
$$
From the CLT
$$
P(\bar X > 10.5148)\approx P\left(Z>{10.5148 - 10.5079 \over \sqrt{0.0832703/100}}\right)\approx P(Z>0.237848)\approx .406
$$
($Z$ is the standard normal).

Comment: The first "=" in the last line should be $\approx$. In fact arguably all the "=" in that line should be $\approx$ but especially the first one.

Comment: @Ian is right. The first $\approx$ is due to the CLT, the others are for numerical precision.